# How to show .shp file on Mapview(ArcGIS Android SDK 2.0.0)

Tags: shapefile, arcgis-android

I'm using ArcGIS Android SDK for first time. I have worked on a sample project and am able to get a World map using this..

```
map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
map.addLayer(new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/ESRI_StreetMap_World_2D/MapServer"));
```

But my problem is:
I have some *.shp (shapefile) files and I would like to show them on mapview.

How can i do that?

Comment: to run without RuntimeException we should have three type of files in a single directory
1 .dbf
2 .shp
3.shx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot add data from a shapefile directly to the MapView. You can only add various types of Layers to the Map View. See this Page for more details: [Map layer types](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgismobile/10.0/apis/android/help/#/Map_layer_types/01190000001n000000/)

You could however create a [Map Tile Package](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000017w000000) from a mapservice and use it instead if you desire offline access, by using it in a [Local Tile Layer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgismobile/10.0/apis/android/help/#/Local_TIle_Layer_Sample/011900000028000000/)

Answer (score 1):

1. Download the shapefile to the device.
2. Make sure that your app has permission to read files from your storage:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` (having permission to write implicitly grants you this permission)

Then, do something like:

```
    try {
        ShapefileFeatureTable shapefileFeatureTable = new ShapefileFeatureTable(shapeFilePath);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.shapefile_not_found, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
```

and to add it to the map:

```
    FeatureLayer featureLayer = new FeatureLayer(shapefileFeatureTable);
    featureLayer.setRenderer(new SimpleRenderer(new SimpleFillSymbol(
            getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright),
            SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE.SOLID)));
    map.addLayer(featureLayer);
```

This should show the feature with a thin black border.